# How to refresh the receipt for validation in failiure cases?

Tags: ios, swift, validation, in-app-purchase, receipt

I have successfully verified sandbox receipt.Now I consider the failure cases.In this case where user shutdown the mobile after purchasing before the receipt send to the server and doesn't on the mobile for some days.How can i handle this?I have no idea.Can anyone please help me? 
Thanks 
Amuthapriya K

Answer (score 0):

Don't finish the transaction with Apple until you've successfully validated and recorded the purchase on your server. The transaction will remain on the payment queue even through app restarts until you finish it.

> Calling finishTransaction: on a transaction removes it from the queue.
>   Your application should call finishTransaction: only after it has
>   successfully processed the transaction and unlocked the functionality
>   purchased by the user.

Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506003-finishtransaction?language=objc

Comment: When should i send  receipt data to our  own server?.Payment process will come to the .purchased state only after the payment process completed right?

Comment: That's correct. You'll probably want to save information on your server after a purchase or restore on the payment queue.